# Can I write this integral differently?

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{d}{du}\int_{g(0)}^{g(u)}f(u,t)\, dt$$

I have an integral of a function $f$ which has variables $u$ and $t$.  Ordinarily I could just move the $d/du$ inside since the integral is with respect to $t$.  But the bound on the integral is a function of $u$.

For what it's worth, $g$ is a linear function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the [Leibniz Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule):

\begin{align}
{d\over du}\int_{g(0)}^{g(u)} f(t,u)\,dt&=\int_{g(0)}^{g(u)} {\partial f\over \partial u}(g(u),u)\,dt+f(g(u),u)g'(u)-f(g(0),u){d\over du}[g(0)]\\
&=\int_{g(0)}^{g(u)} {\partial f\over \partial u}(g(u),u)\,dt+f(g(u),u)g'(u).
\end{align}

Comment: Oh good.  For some reason I've never seen that one before!

Comment: First time for everything! ;-)

Comment: JohnD, to be more specific I am trying to find is 

$\frac{d}{du}$ at u=0 $\int_{t1}^{t0+u}F(f(u,t),g(u,t))\, dt$  Could you help me with this one?